# Water jug for gaining 8 gallons of water?

Tags: decanting-problems

I have gone through simple water jug problems like [this link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2034/a-set-of-water-jug-challenges?rq=1) but when there are 3 jugs:

- 16 Galoon jug with water filled.
- 11 Galoon empty jug.
- 6 Galoon empty jug.

Find a solution to gain 8 Galoon, using these 3 jugs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you may dispose of water...

Call the jugs A, B, C respectively.

- fill C from A. (10,0,6)
- empty C into B. (10,6,0)
- fill C from A. (4,6,6)
- fill B from C. (4,11,1)
- pour out the litre from C (4,11,0)
- empty B into A. (15,0,0)
- fill C from A (9,0,6)
- empty C into B (9,6,0)
- fill C from A. (3,6,6)
- fill B from C. (3,11,1)
- pour out the litre from C (3,11,0)
- empty B into A (14,0,0)
- fill C from A (**8**,0,6)

Jug A now has 8 litres.

If we may not discard water:

- A to C (10,0,6)
- A to B (0,10,6)
- C to A (6,10,0)
- B to C (6,4,6)
- C to A (12,4,0)
- B to C (12,0,4)
- A to B (1,11,4)
- B to C (1,9,6)
- C to A (7,9,0)
- B to C (7,3,6)
- C to A (13,3,0)
- B to C (13,0,3)
- A to B (2,11,3)
- B to C (2,**8**,6)

Jug B now has 8 litres.

Comment: Darn it. Late by a minute. Well done @frodoskywalker.

Comment: also late by a min

Comment: can not dispose the water :(

Comment: @KRU that's fine, I've added a method which doesn't need you to dispose of water.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of producing same result with minimum steps would be as below:

Lets assume 16 Litre jug as A, 11 Litre jug as B and 6 Litre jug as C.

Initial Configuration : (16 0 0)

1. A to C (10 0 6).
2. C to B (10 6 0).
3. A to C ( 4 6 6).
4. C to B (4 11 1).
5. B to A (15 0 1).
6. C to B (15 1 0).
7. A to C (9 1 6).
8. C to B (9 7 0).
9. A to C (3 7 6).
10. C to B (3 11 2).
11. B to A (14 0 2).
12. C to B (14 2 0).
13. A to C (8 2 6).